# Flutter iOS - Reinitialize FlutterEngine and GeneratedPluginRegistrant on runtime

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-ios

I have to reinitialize flutter with different `entrypointArgs` based on certain actions, but I don't know how to regenerate `FlutterEngine` and  `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: )` with the new FlutterEngine (it gives me error of duplicate plugin registered, obviously).

Anybody who faced this situation before can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible because generating the plugins and connecting those to the native required rebuilding the native app itself